# Doing database operations after receiving data from BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-asynctask, broadcastreceiver, android-sqlite

I am using `BroadcastReceiver` that gets the stream of data at regular intervals and then based on that data I am doing certain database operations to insert that data into various tables.

The problem is that although you can do database operations inside `BroadcastReceiver` but the receiver can return at any time. Morever, I like to do such database operations in an `AsyncTask`.

But because it is still not a good practice to start `AsyncTask` from `BroadcastReceiver` for the same reason that Android may kill your process if `onReceive()` returned and there is no other active components running, so I am left with a `Service` (AFAIK) to do database related work. And this Service should manage `AsyncTask`. This way Android will be aware about the active component and Android will not kill the process.

- *Is this the best approach to do so for the given scenario ?*

**That is-**

*BroadcastReceiver* **==>** *Service* **==>** *AsyncTask* **==>** *SQLITE (INSERT)*

And if so, then how about `IntentService` instead of `Service` ?

- *What if I do database operations in BroadcastReceiver itself ?*

I have a singleton Adaptor from `SQLiteOpenHelper` class, so I can use the `context` that I will receive from `onReceive()` of `BroadcastReceiver` to use the adapter for database operations.
But the approach seems inefficient.

Please suggest..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this the best approach to do so for the given scenario ?

I would use an `IntentService` rather than a `Service` with an `AsyncTask`. An `AsyncTask` is only used when you have work that needs to be done on the main application thread, and a service should not have work that needs to be done on the main application thread.

Beyond that, though, having a manifest-registered `BroadcastReceiver` delegate the work to a `Service` is a typical approach.

> What if I do database operations in BroadcastReceiver itself ?

If your UI happens to be in the foreground, it will be frozen while `onReceive()` is executing.

If you take several seconds to do the work, you will get the background equivalent of an ANR and your work will be interrupted without completion.

Hence, I suggest using the `IntentService`.

Comment: But as I know that `IntentService` is itself a `AsyncTask`, so can I do my database operations on `onHandleIntent()` of IntentService ?

Comment: @VedPrakash: "But as I know that IntentService is itself a AsyncTask" -- no, it is not. "so can I do my database operations on onHandleIntent() of IntentService ?" -- yes.

Comment: So do you mean that database operations that will be happen on `onHandleIntent()` will not be `AsyncTask` operations ?

Comment: @VedPrakash: `onHandleIntent()` is called on a background thread. That thread is not implemented using `AsyncTask`.

Comment: I am doing database operations in my broadcast receiver at various conditions. So then will it be a problem to call `IntentService` multiple times (for all those conditions) inside broadcast receiver ?

Comment: @VedPrakash: That should not be a problem. However, if I had to guess, none of that code should be in the `BroadcastReceiver` in the first place, but rather in the `IntentService` itself. Have the `BroadcastReceiver` simply forward the request to the `IntentService`, and let the `IntentService` do the work.

Comment: Ok I will then use `putExtra` for various conditions and my IntentService will identify what to trigger based on that `putExtra` value. Right ?

Comment: I think I got it right now. I will pass all the data to `IntentService` from `Broadcast Receiver` and then will let the `IntentService` do all the work.

Comment: @CommonsWare Could you please give me some pointers as to how to implement an IntentService in onReceive() of the broadcast receiver to update my fragment UI with data from SQLite?

Comment: @ultrasamad: That is well beyond the scope of a Stack Overflow *question*, let alone something that I can cover in a comment, sorry.

Comment: Oh thanks. I have got hold of some materials on that.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try ExecutorService instead of AsyncTask?
Have a look at :
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html